# Which are best practices on Gitflow?

Tags: git, git-flow

We use gitflow in our team. So i have some questions. We are many developpers and each of us have to work on a feature. We'll have many local features branches. 
When someone has to work on a feature :

*git flow feature start MYFEATURE*

1. Is it a best practice to publish the feature ?

*git flow feature publish MYFEATURE*

When someone finish a feature:

*git flow feature finish MYFEATURE*

Finish feature merge my branch on develop, checkout develop and delete MYFEATURE

2. Before finish a feature, what to do ? 
   git checkout develop and pull or merge and pull ?

Answer (score 0):

1.
"git flow feature start MYFEATURE" only start / creates a local feature.
"git flow feature publish MYFEATURE" publishes your branch and does everything what you need

2.
"git flow feature finish MYFEATURE" does all that for you. Personally I don´t use the finish method, because we use pull requests to merge and review our feature/branches

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You don't finish feature ! So your branch are long lives. But i read that gitflow philosophy just two long lives branch : master and develop.

Comment: After the branch is merged we delete the remote one and then everyone has to delete the local ones. Even finishing a feature will not delete the local branches on the machines of the other developers